# Text effects like sublime tool using CSS

Tags: html, css, effect

I want to put code in my webpages as a tutorial. I require CSS code to provide effects like sublime.

Pleases refer this: [cdn.tutorialzine.com](http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/3-emmet.gif)

Different colors for tags, IDs, Class and text as well.

Any solution?

Comment: Why not make class for each of tags? If you prefer CSS over js.

Comment: Just Google it: https://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&q=css+syntax+color+code&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 and you will get for example: http://prismjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is **syntax highlighting**. You can achieve that with libraries like [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/).

Comment: Or with Prism: http://prismjs.com

Answer (score 0):

if your site is developed by wordpress framework you can refer in this link

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/displaying-code/?utm_expid=3606929-97.J2zL7V7mQbSNQDPrXwvBgQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.ph%2F